# Connection in reserved instances is different the connection in instances on demand?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, reserved-instances

I purchased reserved instances and their state is "active", but I do not know how I am supposed to connect to those instances.

Is connecting to reserved instances different from how you connect to regular on-demand instances?
Do I have to do something special here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reserved instances are just a billing thing. The reserved instances shown in that panel don't correspond to actual EC2 instances, they just indicate that you have an active reservation.

To use the reservation, just launch an instance of the right type in the right AZ. AWS will automatically bill that instance's hours at the lower rate. You can delete the instance and replace it with a new one and get the lower rate for that new instance.

Comment: ceejayoz -> I purchased reserved instance in "Availability Zone: us-east-1a" and I create "OnDemand" instance in "Zone: us-east-1a" its ok?
both "Type: m1.small".

Comment: Yep! It's a little confusing the first time - I thought the same thing, that it'd actually create a specific instance, but it's actually just a billing thing and nothing more.